# Pass function or mixin by reference in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Is there any way to pass a function or a mixin by reference to another function or mixin in SASS, and then call the referenced function or mixin?

For example:

```
@function foo($value) {
    @return $value;
}

@mixin bob($fn: null) {
    a {
        b: $fn(c); // is there a way to call a referenced function here?
    }
}

@include bob(foo); // is there any way I can pass the function "foo" here?
```

Comment: You can now pass a function returned by [meta.get-function()](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta#get-function). You still call it with [meta.call()](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta#call).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions and mixins are not *first-class* in Sass, meaning you can't pass them around as arguments like you can with variables.

## Sass 3.2 and older

The closest you can get is with the `@content` directive (Sass 3.2+).

```
@mixin foo {
    a {
        @content;
    }
}

@include bob {
    b: foo(c); // this replaces `@content` in the foo mixin
}
```

The only caveat is that the `@content` can't see what's inside your mixin.  In other words, if `c` was only defined inside the `bob` mixin, it essentially wouldn't exist because it isn't considered in scope.

## Sass 3.3 and newer

Starting with 3.3, you can use the `call()` function, but it is only for use with functions, not mixins.  This requires passing string containing the name of the function as the first argument.

```
@function foo($value) {
    @return $value;
}

@mixin bob($fn: null) {
    a {
        b: call($fn, c);
    }
}

@include bob('foo');
```

Comment: 'Passing a string to call() is deprecated and will be illegal in Dart Sass 2.0.0.' You're now supposed to pass a function returned by [meta.get-function()](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta#get-function).